# Maintaining CMake on Qt Creator

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

I wonder, how do people maintain CMake projects on Qt creator? When you open the project you run CMake generator and after that you can't change much. In order to add another class to the project you have to create class files by hand, add them to CMakeLists.txt and rerun CMake again. Moreover, changing the class name is a nightmare.

I do actually like CMake (except its syntax), since it has some nice features. However, maintaining a project is a nightmare. Am I missing or doing something wrong?

Comment: I always add classes by hand. Most of the time I use Tortiose SVN copy and rename feature from a previous similar class then I search and replace in Notepad++ then I add the header and cxx file entries for the class to the CMakeLists.txt. I have done this with projects up to 300K lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you did not, that is how cmake works: You maintain the build system by hand and generate files for your preferred build system.

That approach makes it pretty easy to support several IDEs/buildsystems using cmake. Unfortunately it also makes it impossible to have an *Integrated* Development Environment for cmake projects. The rather complex syntax which makes it basically impossible for a machine to modify cmake projects does not help there either.